# Can someone solve this limit?

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt[3]{1+x} - \sqrt{1-x}}$$

I have no idea where I should start from

Comment: please don't use external links, use mathjax. and where's your attempt / any ideas at all? even if they are wrong its alright

Comment: Are you *sure* the radicals in the denominator are not both cube roots?

Comment: The roots are correct

Comment: Start by making this limit easier to approach. What can you do to the fraction? (rationalize it)

Comment: I have an idea how to answer, but the question has -3 votes. Please clarify what methods you thought of/already kniw (rationalize the denominator? L'hôpital's rule?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr: Generalize, L'hopital, Spec'd, Answer falls out.

If $u=1+x$, then $-u+2=-x+1$. So letting $2=n$ and $6=p$, we want to solve

$$\lim_{u\to\ 1} \frac{\sqrt[n]{u}-\sqrt[n]{2-u}}{\sqrt[p]{u}-\sqrt[n]{2-u}}$$

Since it's clear lhopital's rule applies (0/0 case), d/du each of the numerator and denominator to get:

$$=\lim_{u\to\ 1} \frac{\frac{u^{-1+1/n} + (2-u)^{-1+1/n}}{n}}{\frac{nu^{-1+1/p} + p(2-u)^{-1+1/n}}{np}}$$

after multiplying and collecting terms
$$=\lim_{u\to\ 1} \frac{p(-u \sqrt[n]{2-u} - (2-u)\sqrt[n] u)}{n(u-2)\sqrt[p] u - pu \sqrt[n]{2-u}}$$
and setting back $n=2, p=6$, we find that our original limit in question is equal to

$$=\lim_{u\to\ 1} \frac{3(-(2-u)\sqrt u  - u\sqrt{2-u})}{2(u-2)\sqrt[3] u - 3u\sqrt{2-u}}$$

Simply plug in $u=1$ into the above and you'll find
$$=\frac 6 5$$

Hope that helps :)

Comment: (Bonus: The 'generalized' limit I wrote here has a very simple algebraic solution in terms of $n,p$ -- can you find it?)

Comment: Thank you
It was perfect